# Access Environment Variables set in XCode within React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

For environment variables set in a particular XCode scheme (DEV, QA, INT, PROD), how do you access those values within React Native?  I have tried both [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) and just process.env but there was no joy. All the examples I have looked at have predisposed starting the application from the command line, in my case, I am starting the React Native app from XCode.